# How does the Stack Overflow diff-between-versions mechanism work?

Tags: support, diff

I'm writing a web app that needs many users to work on the same contents. So there's high probability that one user overwrites another user's changes du to a race condition.

[Ruby on Rails](https://rubyonrails.org/) provides an easy mechanism to prevent this, which is called [optimistic locking](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html). But it only prevents saving when an overwrite would happen, it doesn't help a lot merging those changes.

So whenever Rails fires a `StaleObject` exception, I re-display the form with a warning:

[image]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](https://i.snag.gy/cWRt2.jpg))</sub>

I'm using the [diffy gem](https://github.com/samg/diffy) to display the changes.

This works pretty nice, but the Difference isn't optimised yet: while one-liner (`<input type="text">`) fields are diffed pretty nicely (diff by word), many-liner fields (`<textarea>`) don't give very sophisticated clues about the changes (diff by sentence).

I know from GitHub much more sophisticated diffs (and as a versioning tool, I think git has a lot more possibilities to identify changes and compare them in a human readable way):

[image]

But also Stack Overflow has great diffs:

[image]

So: what mechanism does Stack Overflow use to provide these fine grained diffs? A normal `diff` call on the command line? Some more sophisticated tool like git or something?

It seems that diffing a many-lines text includes at least these steps:

1. Diff by line, so changed lines are detected
2. Diff changed lines by word, to find the fine-grained changes
3. Display only changed lines (with some context lines, if needed), diffed by word

Comment: Übermeta dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128705/248731

Comment: Related: [Side-by-side markdown diff chokes on simple indentation edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258959) "I have just deployed a massive overhaul of the Markdown diff engine. " by [balpha](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha)